# Is it bad to hard code select tags when using option_groups_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working with `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` and haven't seen a way to utilize it on a form tied to a model without hard coding the select tags.  While I've only been working in Rails for a few weeks, it would seem like there is a better way to do this (eg. `collection_select` or even `select`).

Is there a "Rails Way" to avoid hard coding the < select > tag when using `option_groups_from_collection_for_select`?

Code from my view (site has_many categories and I'm trying to group my list by Site)

```
<select id="item_category_id" name="item[category_id]">
    <%= option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Site.all, :categories, :name, :id, :name, @item.category_id) %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with an object in a form_for?  If so does this generate what you need:

```
form_for @item do |f|
  f.grouped_collection_select(:category_id, Site.all, :categories, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)
end
```

or without the form_for

```
grouped_collection_select(:item, :category_id, Site.all, :categories, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)
```

Peer

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly the solution I was looking for!  

I was unable to find anything about it in documentation as I was working with Rails 2.3.2 and this just became available in Rails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 2):

try select_tag instead of select, e.g.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is very close.  The only problem remaining is for some way to include a blank row with :include_blank => true

Comment: Hmm does this work?

<%= select_tag :item, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Site.all, :categories, :name, :id, :name, @item.category_id), { :include_blank => true } %>

Comment: Jen - nope, it does not include a blank option but instead adds it to the select tag (<select id="category_id" include_blank="true" name="category_id">)

Answer (score 0):

Select doesn't work?

```
<%= select :item, :category_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Site.all, :categories, :name, :id, :name, @item.category_id) %>
```

Comment: I've tried that, however, it duplicates the HTML like this:

<option value="&lt;option value=&quot;5&quot;&gt;Jobs &amp;amp; Careers&lt;/option&gt;
">&lt;option value=&quot;5&quot;&gt;Jobs &amp;amp; Careers&lt;/option&gt;
</option>